# How to display a short message next to button when it's pressed?

Tags: html

I have the following html code:

```html
<button onclick="copyText()">copy</button> 
    <script>
        function copyText() {
            navigator.clipboard.writeText
                ("Hello world");
        }
    </script>
```

How do I change the word "copy" to a checkmark and display a short message like "copied to clipboard" next to the button once it's pressed for 1 second and preferably that after 1 second the green checkmark is replaced by the text "copy" again?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, you cannot display native prompts using plain JavaScript. You would have to use something like an alert or a dialog or have a div hide and show the message.

What you need to do is structure your button in such a way that it sits next to an element with your message all aligned inline. You need CSS to accomplish this.

Then when you click on the button, the text gets copied (the code you've wrote so far) and then it should call a function which would then show the "copied" message.

You will again have to call another function to remove the message after a few seconds (or you could could leave it?) This can be done using `setTimeout` function.

See my example for a POC

HTH

```js
function copyText() {
  var secretKey = document.querySelector('samp.my-secret-key').innerText;
  if (secretKey) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(secretKey);
    showNotification();
  }
}

function showNotification() {
  var notificationEl = document.querySelector('.copy-control p.notification-message');

  notificationEl.classList.add('notify');
  setTimeout(function() {
    notificationEl.classList.remove('notify');
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, system-ui, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.secret {
  margin: 2rem auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.secret samp {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) 0 1px 3px 0;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.copy-control {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.notification-message {
  margin: auto 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25%;
  display: none;
}

.notification-message.notify {
  display: block;
}


/* https://getcssscan.com/css-buttons-examples */

.copy-button {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) 0 1px 3px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 3rem;
  padding: calc(.875rem - 1px) calc(1.5rem - 1px);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 250ms;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: auto;
}

.copy-button:hover,
.copy-button:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 4px 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}

.copy-button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.copy-button:active {
  background-color: #F0F0F1;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0 2px 4px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="secret-text">
  <div class="secret">
    <samp class="my-secret-key">45 5F E1 04 22 CA 29 C4 93 3F 95 05 2B 79 2A B2</samp>
  </div>
  <div class="copy-control">
    <button class="copy-button" onclick="copyText()">Copy Text</button>
    <p class="notification-message">Copied!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not do it by functional approach...
Do it by **id** approach, like:-

```
<body>

  <span id="cpnCode">Cupon_Code</span>
  <button id="cpnBtn">Copy</button> 
 
  <script>
       const btn = document.getElementById('cpnBtn');
       const code = document.getElementById('cpnCode');

       btn.addEventListener('click', () => {

          // By clicking, just copy ==> this INNER HTML Content
          navigator.clipboard.writeText(code.innerHTML);
          btn.innerHTML = 'Copied To Clipboard';

          // after clicking 3 second, reset it.
          setTimeout(() => {
              btn.innerHTML = 'Copy';
          }, 3000);

       });
  </script>
  
</body>
```

Hope its will work in your case...

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for, but I also added some styling to the button so I was wondering how I could get the button to return to it's original state instead of changing the innerHTML to some string

Comment: Try to add a CSS class dynamically & toggling that CSS class by JavaScript as per your requirement.